# Problem with autocomplete (jquery)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery, autocomplete

I have problem with autocomplete. The code below is returnig me
["foo@foo.com","bar@bar.com"]

```
   $('.autocomplete').keyup(function() {
    tid = $(this).attr('id')
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (req, resp){           
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: "autocompl.asp", 
                data:$("#msgForm").serialize() + "&field="+tid ,
                    success : function( resp ) {    
                        return resp     
                    }
            })
        }

    });
  });
```

But the suggestions don't appear. It worked for me when I have called autocomplete without any extra parameters. 
Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Magda

Answer (score 0):

Note that one of your parameters for the source function is resp, and you're using another resp afterwards. I think you need to use the first resp to send the response object back.

I'm using this as well and this works for me (Instead of sending an array of values, I'm sending an array of objects with two attributes, but I don't think it's mandatory).

1. id
2. label

so the code inside the ajax success should look something like this (my data variable is your second resp variable, a different name to avoid mixup):

```
success: function(data) {
    for (i in data) {
        a = {}
        a.id = data[i]
        a.label = data[i]
        options.push(a)
    }
    resp(options)
}
```